# WSO2 IS-KM and WSO2 AM with HA

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to implement a double HA solution with WSO2AM and WSO2IS as KeyManager.

Actually I have 2 nodes, WSO2AM and WSOIS-KM is installed on each one and works perfectly. Both nodes access and write on the same database.
The issues stars when I try to acces to an application registered on store, from the other node that it was created.

I installed WSO2AM 2.6.0 and IS-KM 5.7.0 on centos environment. Both AM and IS-KS runs on the same node with por offset. I have 2 nodes configured like that.

Example of the issue:

From node 1 I access to store of node 1 and create a new app. I generate the tokens and keys without any issues. After that, I access to the store of node 2, I saw the same application, but when I try to access and view tokens it throw an exception like the OAuth token does not exists or something like that ( I forget to take a proof of that).

I understand that I have to make WSO2AM in HA but I'm not quite sure if I have to deploy WSO2IS as HA and after that convert to KM or what exactly I have to do.

Basically I want to have both roles in HA and both Stores access the same apps with the sames tokens regardless of the node that is sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure both API Manager nodes (node01 & node02) with IS as Key Manager to achieve your use case.

If you are using only one IS Key manager instance and two API Manager nodes, then it is required to front both the API Manager nodes with a load balancer (HA deployment with sticky sessions enabled & datasources are shared among all the nodes) and configure the API Manager as follows

API Manager Nodes: *api-manager.xml* *(assumption IS-KM port offset 1, therefore 9444)*

```
<AuthManager>
  <!-- Server URL of the Authentication service -->
  <ServerURL>https://localhost:9444/services/</ServerURL>
  ...
</AuthManager>
...
<APIKeyValidator>
  <!-- Server URL of the API key manager -->
  <ServerURL>https://localhost:9444/services/</ServerURL>
  ...
</APIKeyValidator>
```

IS Key Manager Node: *api-manager.xml*

```
<APIGateway>
  <Environments>
    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
      ...
      <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
      <ServerURL>https://loadbalancer/services/</ServerURL>
      ...
</APIGateway>
```

Sample NGINX

```
upstream mgtnode {
  server localhost:9443; # api manager node 01
  server localhost:9443; # api manager node 02
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name mgtgw.am.wso2.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
  ...
  location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass https://mgtnode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, but how can I achieve to create also IS-KM in HA and do not get issues with the access token? Actually I have deployed two nodes for each role but I’m having several issues.